# Sequelize in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, npm, sequelize.js

Since once year i start programmin in windows. Now i decided to start using a Linux dist and chosose Ubuntu.
I have a problem using sql and sequelize in ubuntu.
When i use windows, to create a DB just use `sequelize db:create` but now in ubuntu whe i clone my projects from github, install dependencis and run `sequelize db:create` i get the message  `sequelize: command not found`
I maded the installation of

`sudo apt-get install update`
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client`
`sudo mysql_secure_installation`

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you already have `node` installed and installed all dependencies via `npm install` on the ubuntu.

In your project folder, use the following command to run sequelize:

```
npx sequelize db:create
```

> `npx` will find `sequelize` cli in the `node_modules` to run the command. If `sequelize` is not found, `npx` will download the latest `sequelize` to run.

---

For the reason why your windows work with just typing `sequelize db:create`, I think you installed `sequelize` globally via `npm install -g sequelize` before.

You can also install it globally on ubuntu but I recommend you to do it in `npx` way to **use the same sequelize version** in DDL, DML throughout the project.

Comment: Okay i maded that but i've now a new error
`npm ERR! could not determine executable to run`
`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /home/facundo/.npm/_logs/2021-05-25T16_42_01_433Z-debug.log
`

Comment: Are you running npx command inside your project directory? If yes, did you use sudo to do npm install - `sudo npm install` before?

Comment: Oh ididnt know the sudo was necessary
Yes, i was running it in project dir

Comment: you don't need to use sudo to run npm install, just asking only.

Comment: I think there is a conflict of your node_modules, maybe 1. you did not git ignore node_modules when pushing and the node_modules are from the windows side. 2. used sudo to install dependencies.

Try to remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` on ubuntu side. In your project directory, run `rm -rf node_modules` and `rm -rf package-lock.json` to remove it and run `npm install` again

Comment: Okay that was the problem! Ty very much

Comment: Cool. So are you able to run `sequelize` now ? If yes, please kindly accept and upvote the answer :)

Comment: Sure. Where is that option? im new srry

Comment: You should see a grey tick icon, a zero, and up/down arrows on the left hand side next to my answer. you can click the  tick icon and up arrow to accept and upvote the answer. you will earn point as well. can follow this link to have a illustration of the flow: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/994617

Comment: Ok i tried but page says

"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: oh. you may not have enough point to upvote it but you can still "tick" the answer